# Error submitting Alamofire to App Store, using Carthage

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, alamofire, carthage

I get the following errors when submitting to the app store. I've followed all the instructions in the Carthage Readme and the Alamofire Readme. My iOS version is set to Latest (8.1).

Everytime I search for these errors, people say, it doesn't work for iOS 7. Ok. But I'm building for iOS 8.

[Here is my GitHub repo illustrating this problem, along with screenshots.](https://github.com/danramteke/EmbeddedFrameworkTestApp) I made a blank Single Page App, and added Alamofire via Carthage 0.5.3. I added all files.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Imgur link to errors screen shot: http://imgur.com/6lQDvyE

Comment: Have you tried setting alamofire target version to 8.1 ? I think your app build target should be same with all other libraries

Comment: I do not want modify the Alamofire code, so that I can rely fully on the package manager for updates.

Comment: Can you please [open an issue](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/new) with this information, where we can talk about this in more detail (and with other Carthage contributors)?

Comment: im sure you added the carthage script copy phase BEFORE the embebed binaries phase or no emebed binaries phase at all in the build phases!